Constructing a System of Two Cubic Polynomial Equations with Exactly 9 Real Solutions in Maple
I am trying to construct a system of two cubic polynomial equations in two variables (x and y) with exactly 9 real solutions using Maple. However, I am having trouble finding the appropriate coefficients for the polynomials to ensure exactly 9 real solutions.
Here is the system
$$ a_1 x^3 + a_2 x^2 y + a_3 x y^2 + a_4 x^2 + a_5 xy + a_6 y^2 + a_7 x + a_8 y =0 $$
$$ b_1 x^3 +b_2 y^3 + b_3 x^2 y + b_4 x y^2 + b_5 x^2 + b_6 xy + b_7 y^2 + b_8 x + b_9 y =0 $$
I would appreciate any guidance on how to construct such a system, ensuring exactly 9 real solutions with $x$ non-negative. Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Take a cubic in $x$ with distinct real roots and a cubic in $y$ with distinct real roots!

And if you want the equations to be coupled, then do a linear transformation e.g. $X = x + y$, $Y = x - y$.

The second version of the Cayley Bacharach theorem on wikipedia says that the ninth is determined by a previously chosen eight. So if you want any given nine points, you're probably out of luck...
